# How do I create a function for exporting CSV files with varying number of variables into a dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I wrote the code below to import a CSV file into a dictionary. Now, I would like to create a function that can work for importing CSV files with numerous variables, where the names of dictionary keys are the same as the created list titles.

```
import csv

# My Dictionary

BL_Music_Records = dict()

#Lists:

id_list = []
shelfmark_list = []
composer_life_list = []
composer_list = []
ISBN_list = []
ISMN_list = []
location_list = []
publication_date_nstd_list = []
publication_date_std_list = []
publisher_number_list = []
publisher_list = []
title_list = []

#uploading the csv file

with open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', newline = '', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

      # updating the lists
      for row in reader:
          id_list.append((row['BL record ID']))
          shelfmark_list.append((row['BL shelfmark']))
          composer_life_list.append((row['Composer life dates']))
          composer_list.append((row['Composer']))
          ISBN_list.append((row['ISBN']))
          ISMN_list.append((row['ISMN']))
          location_list.append((row['Place of publication']))
          publication_date_nstd_list.append((row['Publication date (not standardised)']))
          publication_date_std_list.append((row['Publication date (standardised)']))
          publisher_number_list.append((row['Publisher number']))
          publisher_list.append((row['Publisher']))
          title_list.append((row['Title']))

          #updating the dictionary

          BL_Music_Records.update(
               {
                "id_list": id_list,
                "shelfmark_list": shelfmark_list,
                "composer_life_list": composer_life_list,
                "composer_list": composer_list,
                "ISBN_list": ISBN_list,
                "ISMN_list": ISMN_list,
                "location_list": location_list,
                "publication_date_nstd_list": publication_date_nstd_list,
                "publication_date_std_list": publication_date_std_list,
                "publisher_number_list": publisher_number_list,
                "publisher_list": publisher_list,
                "title_list": title_list
                }
                )

print(BL_Music_Records.keys())
print(BL_Music_Records.values())
```

Comment: Please add a worked example to your question so we can better understand what you are hoping to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need dynamic code generation, based on CSV content. I'm working on the library which does so and provides lots of data processing primitives -- [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

with open(
    "bl_printed_music_500.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8-sig"
) as csvfile:
    table = Table.from_csv(csvfile)

    columns = table.columns
    converter = c.aggregate(
        {
            "{}_list".format(column_name): c.ReduceFuncs.Array(
                c.item(column_name)
            )  # replace with c.ReduceFuncs.ArrayDistinct if only unique ones are needed
            for column_name in columns
        }
    ).gen_converter()

    # returns a dict:
    #  where keys are columns names
    #  and values are lists of all column values
    results = converter(table.into_iter_rows(dict))
```